# Deleted versus non-deleted limits

Tags: real-analysis

When I read Serge Lang's Undergraduate Analysis(second edition) page 41,  I found the definition of limit he define is so called 
[non-Deleted limits](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Limit_of_a_function#Deleted_versus_non-deleted_limits), this results in some conclusion is different from the usual limit( deleted limit), for example, every isolated point $x_0$ has limit, its value is $f(x_0)$. By topology knowledge, we know every isolated point is continuous, we cannot get this result by $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)$, if we define limit as deleted limit. However, if we define limit as non-deleted limit, we can get it.

My question: is non-deleted limit better than deleted limit, if yes, why does most textbook do not use it?

Comment: I think the existence of non-deleted limits is more or less equivalent to continuity.

Comment: The two concepts agree for $x \to x_0$ provided $x_0$ happens *not* to be in the domain of $f.$ But if $x_0$ is in fact in the domain of $f$ the nondeleted limit existence implies continuity of $f$ at $x_0.$

Answer (score 3):

A good place to get information on deleted and non-deleted limits is
Robert G. Bartle's Elements of Real Analysis, J. Wiley & Sons 1964, p. 195

Answer (score 2):

Hubbard and Hubbard's *Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra, and Differential Forms* claims that deleted limits are standard in the U.S. but non-deleted limits are common in France. One thing that is nice about deleted limits is that they are sometimes defined when non-deleted limits aren't. In the book, they use non-deleted limits because it makes limits much more well-behaved under compositions. Specifically, if
$$y_0 = \lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) \quad \textrm{and} \quad z_0 = \lim_{y \to y_0} g(y)$$
both exist, then $\lim_{x \to x_0} g(f(x))$ exists and
$$\lim_{x \to x_0} g(f(x)) = z_0.$$
This is not true for deleted limits.